# Object returned by Jquery.find behaving unexpectedly with .data()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Take a look at this example :

```js
let ele = $(`
    <div></div>
  <div class="test" id="test" data-test="test"></div>`
);

const ele1 = ele.find('.test'); //undefined
const ele2 = ele.find('#test'); //undefined

console.log(ele1.data());
console.log(ele2.data());

ele = $('<div class="test" id="test" data-test="test"></div>');
console.log(ele.data()); //works
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

There seems to be a difference between the object returned by `.find()` and the one returned by `$()`

I'm assuming it has something to do with the first `ele` being two siblings with no parent, but considering this **can't be changed**, how can I get `#test`'s data?

I couldn't find anywhere what's the expected behaviour when you create an element with no parent like I did, and why does this happens.

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/26285/

Comment: You're missing a `>` on the opening <div> tag. Does that help?

Comment: @AndrewChart thanks fixed it, but no thats not it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just wrap that HTML inside a single div to be able to use `find()` on it. But, if you can't change the HTML, you can do it using `filter()`, since it's a collection of jQuery elements:

```js
// Your element, as you defined it in your question
let ele = $(`
    <div></div>
  <div class="test" id="test" data-test="test"></div>`
);

console.log(ele.filter('.test').data());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is that really the only way, it seems so odd

Comment: Well, your question is odd ;-)